# How to detect when Voiceover has finished reading out elements on the screen?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have an alert that pops up when I click on a certain button. I have Voiceover enabled on my device, it starts reading contents on the popup. Now, I want to make a custom announcement like

`UIAccessibility.post(notification: .announcement, argument: "Hello world.")`

But this does not work, as I need to post this notification only when Voiceover has finished reading everything that's on the screen.

Is there anyway I can post this notification when Voiceover is done reading everything?

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe (add an observer) to the NotificationCenter event `announcementDidFinishNotification`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibility/1620202-announcementdidfinishnotificatio

or `voiceOverStatusDidChangeNotification`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibility/2865862-voiceoverstatusdidchangenotifica

The function selector you added to the observer will be called with the parameter `_ sender: Notification` just like other observer selectors.
Let me know this helps ;)

Comment: My understanding of this is that it is triggered when custom announcement is finished, and not when the system announcement is. 

I've tried this out on my project and this notification is not triggered when Voiceover finishes reading out elements on screen.

Comment: Have you tried `voiceOverStatusDidChangeNotification`?

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibility/2865862-voiceoverstatusdidchangenotifica

Also, you can call `UIAccessibility. isVoiceOverRunning` to check if VoiceOver is currently running.

Comment: @Stephen, `isVoiceOverRunning`: **Returns a Boolean value indicating whether the user has enabled VoiceOver.** So your message in incorrect!